# What is the number of passwords can be made under this restriction?

Tags: combinatorics

I'm facing difficulties while solving this problem:
A password contains 5 digit numbers and 5 small english letters.
how many possible passwords can be made?

If I solve it like this: `26^5 x 10^5` this will not count passwords that are mixed and digit-first passwords.

Comment: You're right that $26^5 10^5$ is the number of passwords that match the pattern LLLLLNNNNN. How many patterns are possible?

Comment: @Karl Each password must have 5 digits and 5 letters. Other than this there are no more restrictions. So any pattern that has 5 digits and 5 letters, is allowed.

Comment: How many ways are there of choosing $~5~$ positions out of $~10,~$ sampling without replacement, where order of selection is regarded as unimportant?  The $~5~$ selected positions can be regarded as the positions that the digits will occupy, with the letters going in the remaining positions.

Comment: @user2661923 Is this a question or what? In mine the order is important and it is with replacement/repetition

Comment: Good thoughtful response that overlooks something.  Assume that you choose (any) 5 positions for the digits, with the letters going in the remaining 5 positions.  Then, how many choices do you have for **each** of the 5 digit positions, and how many choices do you have for **each** of the 5 letter positions?  To answer this question, consider the work that you have already shown.

Comment: From the perspective of my previous comment, you are choosing the $~5~$ positions without replacement, where order of selection is unimportant.  For example, if you choose positions 1 thru 5 for the digits, does it matter which order they were selected in.  Further, once you choose (for example) position-1 for one of the digits, that position is now **taken**, and can not be selected again.  This is what the phrase *without replacement* signifies.

Comment: @user2661923 answering your question if we fixed the 5 numbers then it will be 26^5. If we fixed the 5 letters this time, then it will be 10^5. But how can this help?

Comment: The number of ways of selecting the 5 digit positions, out of 10, sampling without replacement, where order of selection is regarded as irrelevant is $~\displaystyle \binom{10}{5} = \frac{10!}{(10-5)! \times 5!} = 252.~$ See also [Pascal's Triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle), and note that $~\displaystyle \binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{(n-k)! \times k!}.$

Comment: @user2661923 Oh, you meant choosing the positions. Okay if we have 252 and 252 for the letters then how can this help? Sorry I'm very bad at this.

Comment: I don't know what else to say.  Is this an assigned problem from a math course?  Perhaps you could ask your teacher for help, or ask the school if a tutor is available?

Comment: @user2661923  Sorry it will be different for the letters since, n=26 and k=5.

Comment: @user2661923 It is an old exam question. However, thank you for your time.

Comment: MSE is not a discussion forum. Per site policy, comments should only be used to clarify, not answer the question. See **[How do comments work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19756)** for more information. Therefore I suggest that you post your answers here from the comments as an answer. This brings extra visibility to the answer und puts the question off the unanswered list. Also notice that comments are not indexed by the full text search, don't have any revision history, can only be edited for 5 minutes and allow only limited markup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the work you have already done you have calculated the probability of a password with the position of the numbers and digit fixed. Namely the first five are letters only and the next five are digits only, but this is only one possible way of fixing the positions of the letters and digits. How many ways can they be fixed? Would it be possible to calculate the probability for each of the many ways of fixing the positions? How would you do so?

Comment: Oh, then multiplying my work by 10 will be the answer?

Comment: are there only 10 ways to fix the positions?

Comment: NNNNNLLLLL will be 26^5 x 10^5. LLLLLNNNNN will be also 26^5 x 10^5. Continuing like this it will have 2^10 different permutation. So the answer will be: **2^10 x 26^5 × 10^5** right?

Comment: not exactly $2^{10}$ since everytime a digit or letter is used the chances of the next draw get affected it is not $50|50$ anymore. This means the positions of letters and digits are being chosen "without replacement".

Comment: My bad you are right. I think I understood know. Using the counting rule for combinations without replacement the answer will be **45 x 26^5 x 10^5**. correct, right?

Comment: What is the counting rule for combinations? How did you arrive at $45$?

Comment: using this: (n!) / ((n-r)! x r!). when r=2 and n=10.

Comment: are you sure $r=2$ in our case? you might want to look back at the comments on your question.

Comment: 5? I don't really know I'm very bad at this.

Comment: Lets put an $L$ in every position that's fixed for a letter. You are trying to figure out how many different positions the five $L$s can take out of $10$ possible positions.

Comment: It is more clear now. Appreciate it.